# Should the tag [asp.net-core-razor-pages] be merged into [razor-pages]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

According to the tag info for [razor-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor-pages) (3,743 questions):

> Apply to questions related to the Razor Pages Framework, which is a feature of ASP.NET Core starting in ASP.NET Core version 2.0.
>
> Note that Razor Pages is separate from Razor, which is a templating syntax used in Views in both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core. You should only apply the Razor Pages tag to questions that are specifically about the Razor Pages framework, not just questions about Razor or ASP.NET (Core) Views.

And for [asp.net-core-razor-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-razor-pages) (92 questions):

> Use this tag for questions specifically related to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, in addition to using the 'ASP.NET Core' tag.

If [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) is indeed only available in ASP.NET Core and not .NET Framework, why do we need both tags?  Occam's Razor suggests this is a mistake, and [asp.net-core-razor-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-razor-pages) should get merged into [razor-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor-pages).

That being said, there are 31 questions tagged [`[asp.net-core-razor-pages] -[asp.net-core]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-razor-pages+-asp.net-core) so perhaps we should give then a look to make sure they aren't mistagged before doing the merge.

Comment: I'm not sure why a question would necessarily need both [asp.net-core-razor-pages] and [asp.net-core]. I typically remove [asp.net-core] from [asp.net-core-mvc] questions, if I happen to be editing the question. I mean, if you can't figure out that [asp.net-core-razor-pages] has something to do with [asp.net-core], you've got more problems than just Razor. People can search/subscribe to [asp.net-core*] to get all of the tags they want.... To me, however, I'd make the master [asp.net-core-razor-pages] and make [razor-pages] the synonym. But I'm weird like that :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - possibly [asp.net-core-razor-pages] requires [asp.net-core] because it's such an obscure tag that nobody watches it, and so questions with only that tag don't get answered.,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, "razor pages" is the specific feature, and clearly the established tag here. Razor Pages is also only usable with ASP.NET Core, so there's not really a need to have that language name be in the tag, given that every question using [razor-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor-pages) should also be using [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) already, anyway.

Comment: Those with 2500+ rep plus a score of 5 in the tag [tag:razor-pages] can suggest [tag:asp.net-core-razor-pages] as a synonym here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/razor-pages/synonyms.

Comment: "Razor Pages is also only usable with ASP.NET Core" - which is all fun and games until someone comes up with the brilliant idea of naming a product "Razor" and have a submodule for some type of page. People don't read tag wikis, so the tag name is the last hail mary for tag disambiguation (at least with Stack's tag model, which is honestly fundamentally flawed, but that's a discussion for not now). I'll still go ahead with the merge as requested, but specific names are far less prone to future naming clashes that require more cleanup and disambiguation